# Elder-Dragon-Highlander versus Commander tags

Tags: discussion

This is probably an easy question, but it gave me pause.

We currently have questions on the site relating to both EDH and Commander - which are synonyms for the same Magic format.  EDH has been "officially rebranded" as Commander, but it's still fine to call it EDH if you're a traditionalist.

It would be nice to merge these tags together, but neither of them is obviously the wrong tag.  Should we go with "Commander" because it's the more up-to-date term?

Answer (score 4):

Make a tag synonym ... also add edh as a synonym.

I lack sufficient rep for synonym creation, but you should be able to.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the name Elder Dragon Highlander is not mentioned even once in the [Magic comprehensive rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules), and the [official EDH/Commander website](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php) mentions that Commander is the modern name for the format, Commander should definitely be the actual tag, and Elder Dragon Highlander a synonym of it.